# How to add Class in javascript using button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to trying adding class using javascript, I know there is a lot of topic about this in stackoverflow but some of them is too complicated for me to understand, let say I have this simple code

this is some topic that I already read:

[addclass-to-getelementsbyclassname-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897781/addclass-to-getelementsbyclassname-array)

[add-css-class-using-document-getelementsbyclassname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37738852/add-css-class-using-document-getelementsbyclassname)

[add-class-using-getelementsbyclassname-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36086763/add-class-using-getelementsbyclassname-javascript)

this is my html

```
<p>
    test 1
  </p>
  <h2 class="test-2">
    test 2
  </h2>
  <h3 class="test-3">
    test 2
  </h3>

  <button onClick="addClass">
    click me
  </button>
```

this is my css:

```
p{
  color: red;
}

.test-2{
  font-size: 2em;
  color: blue;
}

.test-3{
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

and this is my js:

```
function addClass () {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("test-3")[0]; 
 return  x[0].className += ' test-2';
}
```

where did I do it wrong? I'm quite confused since I'm new in javascript

Comment: Put () after addClass.  <button onClick="addClass()">
    click me
  </button>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a live collection of elements. Grabbing the first index `[0]` is correct, but you don't need to do it a second time:

```
x.className += ' test-2'
```

You may find using [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) and [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) a little easier as their interfaces are newer and often more suitable for modern JS development.

`querySelector` allows you to use CSS selectors to select elements, and returns the first instance of an element found with that selector. (Its sister method [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) returns a (non-live) nodelist which you can iterate over).

`classList` allows you to simply add and remove classes from an element without the need to concatenate class strings to each other.

Here's a demo.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
button.addEventListener('click', addClass, false);

function addClass() {
  var x = document.querySelector('.test-3');
  x.classList.add('test-2');
}
```

```css
p { color: red; }
.test-2 { font-size: 2em; color: blue; }
.test-3 { font-size: 5em; font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<p>test 1</p>
<h2 class="test-2">test 2</h2>
<h3 class="test-3">test 2</h3>
<button>click me</button>
```

Comment: thankyou for the explanation it really easy for me to understand

Answer (score 3):

Remove the extra [0] when adding classname and do not return that from the function

```js
function addClass () {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("test-3")[0]; 
   x.className += ' test-2';
   console.log(x.getAttribute("class"))
}
```

```css
p{
  color: red;
}

.test-2{
  font-size: 2em;
  color: blue;
}

.test-3{
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>
    test 1
  </p>
  <h2 class="test-2">
    test 2
  </h2>
  <h3 class="test-3">
    test 2
  </h3>

  <button onclick="addClass()">
    click me
  </button>
```

Comment: yups it works for me Thankyou, so I only miss the indexing `[0]` there